# Delphi 10.2 Tokyo no longer supports IMAGE_FILE_LARGE_ADDRESS_AWARE?

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.2-tokyo

According to the [DocWiki](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Increasing_the_Memory_Address_Space) which was simply probably not updated, the  following should be a valid directive in a .pas file:

`{$SetPEFlags IMAGE_FILE_LARGE_ADDRESS_AWARE}`

However it causes this dcc32 error:

`[dcc32 Error] Project1.dpr(13): E2003 Undeclared identifier: 
  'IMAGE_FILE_LARGE_ADDRESS_AWARE'`

Has this ability been lost, or is it now always on?

Comment: Works as before. Have you included `Winapi.Windows` module?

Comment: That was the problem.  I didn't realize that it reads the names of these flags from a .pas file from the uses clause.  I keep forgetting that in Pascal, it really "ain't no precompiler" in there, it's just a weird syntax.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`IMAGE_FILE_LARGE_ADDRESS_AWARE` is declared in Windows.pas (WinAPI.Windows in recent Delphi versions). You've apparently not included it in the unit where you've put the directive. If you're avoiding that for some reason, define it yourself:

```
IMAGE_FILE_LARGE_ADDRESS_AWARE = $0020;
```

Answer (score 4):

`IMAGE_FILE_LARGE_ADDRESS_AWARE` is declared in the `Winapi.Windows` unit. You must use that unit in order to be able to use the identifier.